# How to call a function from another file in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function from a React component. This function will call another function in the component from which it was called.

My component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// import turnOnGreenLight from "./green.js"; // <-- I want to import this

export const initialLightValues = ["unactive", "unactive"];
export let setLightsVar = initialLightValues;

function App() {

  const [lights, setLights] = useState(initialLightValues);

  function turnOnRedLight() {
    setLightsVar[0] = "active";
    updateLightsState();
    turnOnGreenLight();
  }

  // I want to move this function "turnOnGreenLight" in the file green.js
  function turnOnGreenLight() {
    setLightsVar[1] = "active";
    updateLightsState();
  }

  function updateLightsState() {
    setLightsVar = setLightsVar.slice();
    setLights(setLightsVar);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => turnOnRedLight()}>Turn on the lights</button>
      <br />
      <div className={"red-light " + lights[0]}>Red</div>
      <div className={"green-light " + lights[1]}>Green</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The function in the file green.js would look like this:

```
import { setLightsVar, updateLightsState } from "./App";

function turnOnGreenLight() {
  setLightsVar[1] = "active";
  updateLightsState();
}

export default turnOnGreenLight;
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but you will get circular modules warning, and if you will run jest tests it will throw exception, so if you want to do this better pass the function updateLightsState as a callback parameter - then no problems

```
function turnOnGreenLight(callback) {
  setLightsVar[1] = "active";
  callback();
}

turnOnGreenLight(updateLightsState)
```

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand how to pass the function updateLightsState as a callback parameter.